# Let user know of long operation when initiating request to download file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some routine code which downloads a file (as below). However, while this is processed (there is lag time between the request to download the file and the save dialog box coming up), I want to add some sort of JavaScript modal alert to let the user know of the pending operation. How could I easily do this from a user control?

```
 System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
 response.ClearContent();
 response.Clear();


 response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName + ";");
 response.TransmitFile(zipFilePath);
 response.Flush();
 response.End();
```

Comment: you could likely send the flush after adding your headers and that would make the save dialog pop quicker...

Comment: True.... Still need to display some sort of alert to the user!

Comment: if you know the file size can't you put that in the header then the browser should pick up on it and show the progress of how much is downloaded vs the size of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to show the javascript alert first, then simply redirect the browser to the download URL, no?

Something along the lines of:

```
function alertAndDownload() {
    if (!confirm("You are about to be redirected to a file download.  This may take a while!  Is that ok?")) return;
    window.location = "http://yoursite.com/goDownloadTheirThing.aspx";
}
```